# how to get character position of a word in a character array

Tags: java

I have a string which i've made into a `characterArray`

`public static String Text = "hello hi bye";`

Im trying to find the character position of `hi`  but am currently struggling to get the full word as what i am comparing right now is each index which is wrong. How would i go about comparing full words from a character array without using inbuilt string functions?

Here is my current code;

```
public static HashMap<String, List<Integer>> SubtextResults = new HashMap<>();

public static String Text = "hello hi bye";

public static void addSubText(String text){

        SubtextResults.put(text, new ArrayList<>());

        char[] charArray = Text.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){
            for(String key: SubtextResults.keySet()){
                if(key.toLowerCase().contains(String.valueOf(charArray[i]).toLowerCase())){ // Wrong here, comparing letters instead of word/key
                    System.out.println(charArray[i] + " " + i); 
                    SubtextResults.get(key).add(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this could help. Essentially why not split the string by common delimiters and work with worlds (as seems to be what you want to accomplish) https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/01/how-to-split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-java.html

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing as you are using `String` methods such as `toCharArray()`, `toLowerCase()`, and `contains()`.  Exactly what String methods do you not want to use and why?

Comment: @WJS  seems its the question is part of some assignment  for usage of loops and logic, but yep the most sorted out solution is Matcher for such cases, that i personally use , why not use it when java gives it to us Code reusalbility :)

Comment: @WJS nice pointing out the use of all the Inbuilt string functions

Answer (score 0):

Without use of any String In built function just used toCharArray for conversion
as starting point

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        String mainText = "hello hi bye";
        String searchText = "hi";
        char[] mainTextArray = mainText.toCharArray();
        char[] searchTextArray = searchText.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(position(searchTextArray, mainTextArray));
    }


    public static int position(char[] searchTextArray, char[] mainTextArray) {
        int foundposition =-1;
        boolean foundFlag =false;

        for (int i = 0; i < mainTextArray.length - searchTextArray.length+1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < searchTextArray.length; j++) {
                if (mainTextArray[i + j] == searchTextArray[j]) {
                    if (j == searchTextArray.length - 1) {
                        foundposition = i;
                        foundFlag = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(foundFlag)
        { return foundposition; }
      else
      { return -1;

      }
    }
```

Simpler way but uses library function

Try with Matcher class provided by java , follow http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html#find-start-end-methods

```
  String text    =
                "This is the text which is to be searched " +
                "for occurrences of the word 'is'.";

        String patternString = "is";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        int count = 0;
        while(matcher.find()) {
            count++;
            System.out.println("found: " + count + " : "
                    + matcher.start() + " - " + matcher.end());
        }
    }
```

Official Docs about [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) Class

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Character ArrayList and use the subList method then convert it back into a String for those specified indexes but even that uses some kind of "String" method I don't see any perspective which could be used to lengthen out more than one character and get away without using String in some way.

```
character.subList(0, 3).toString().replaceAll("[^a-z|0-9]+", "")
```

The replaceAll( startIndex , endIndex ) here is to get rid of spaces and tabs ( [ , , ] ) after we toString() it. But if you do this might aswell use the original String you have generated prior the character array.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use in-built string functions then you should probably use a lot more for loops and arrays.

The first thing you should do is split the string into an array of characters which is essentially done by the toCharArray() method but I am guessing you can't use that because it is in-built.

You need to compare each character on your string (from the array you just created) with the characters on the string you want the positions of. The problem here is that you need to hold the right positions in a new array. If you encounter "h" in the beginning of the string but "i" much later then the word you encountered probably wasn't "hi", therefore you should compare each character and reset the array's positions whenever necessary until you find what you are looking for.

There are obviously much easier ways to deal with this(like in-built string methods that you apparently can't use) but I'm guessing this is an assignment that requires you to learn about strings, characters, arrays and for loops. Once you get the fundamentals of those this should be pretty easy.

I also don't think that the hashmap is necessary there for a problem like this unless of course it is required for some reason.